# Can't resolve 'tslib' in 'node_modules/rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Im trying to use rxjs 6-beta in an angular 6 beta project

`ng serve`, `ng test`, `ng build`, `build --prod --build-optimizer=false` is working

But `ng build --prod` is generating an error Can't resolve `tslib`

```
TS version 2.7.2
RxJS version:6 beta-1
RxJS rxjs-compat installed
Angular 6-rc-0
```

Code to reproduce:

Expected behavior: ng build --prod

Actual behavior: `Error: Can't resolve 'tslib' in 'node_modules/rxjs'`